# Laravel : Can't move file if I use custom Form Request Class

Tags: php, laravel, validation, request

I'm facing some strange problem when try to move file (image) with Laravel: when I create custom Form request class and after validation is passed, I'm receiving an error, **but** the file is moved regularly.

**Here is my controller:**

```
(...)
class ArticleController extends Controller{ 

  public function store(StoreArticleRequest $request){
    $article = new Article;

    if ($request->hasfile('image')){
     $name= rand(1, 10000).$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName() ;
     $move = $request->file('image')->move(public_path().'/images/articles/', $name);
     $article->image = $name;
    }

   $article->title = request('title');
   $article->preview = request('preview');
   $article->text = request('content');
   $article->user_id = \Auth::user()->id;
   $article->source = request('source');


   $article->save();
   return view('admin.dashboard');
 }
```

**...and here is the Form request class:**

```
(...)
class StoreArticleRequest extends FormRequest{

   public function authorize(){
    return true;
   }

   public function rules(){
    return [
        'title' => 'required|unique:articles',
        'source' => 'required',
    ];
   }

public function messages(){
 return [
    'title.required' => 'foo',
    'title.unique' => 'bar',
    'source.required'  => 'baz',
 ];
 }

}
```

**This way, *although the file is moved to the required location*, I'm receiving an error:**

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpFoundation \ File \ Exception \ FileNotFoundException
The file "/tmp/php9lQ7wd" does not exist
```

**If I use the same code, but if I change an argument of store method in ArticleController, there is no error and files are moved normally:**

```
public function store(Request $request){
   (...the rest of the code in this method is exactly the same...)
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Is there a way to fix this?
TIA, Ognjen

*Laravel version: 5.7

**UPDATE: Solved**

There was no any strange Laravel behaviour, just a lack of my concentration.
The problem was that I forgot to add the following line to store method (when use StoreArticleRequest):

```
$validated = $request->validated();
```

Comment: Are you maybe forgetting to import the custom request like this at the top of the class:
`use App\Http\Requests\StoreArticleRequest;`

Comment: I imported custom request and other necessary classes. That isn't a problem but thanks for try.
Validation is passed, but I got the described error that is related to moving a file.